# how to manage _id field when using POCO with mongodb c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, poco

If I want to read and write mongo data with a POCO

```
public class Thingy
{
     public string Foo {get;set;}
}
...
coll.Insert(new Thing(Foo = "hello"));
```

When I read back I get a failure saying that _id is an unexpected attribute (which it is). So then I added a field called _id to the class. Now the insert doesnt work saying that the _id field cannot be null. A tried BsonIgnoreIfNull attribute, that didnt work.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

When you insert an object, if it doesn't have an `_id` field then the driver adds one and sets it to a 12-byte MongoDB [ObjectId](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs) value.

You just need to add an `Id` property to your POCO, which will be deserialised from `_id`:

```
public class Thingy
{
     public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
}
```

Or, if you'd like to delegate another property to map onto `_id` then you can decorate it with the `BsonIdAttribute`, like this:

```
[BsonId]
public ObjectId MyKey { get; set; }
```

The `_id` field doesn't have to be an MongoDB `ObjectId`, you can set it to any value of any data type (except an array), it just needs to be unique within the collection.

Comment: +1 for the final explanation that the _id can be set to any value of any data type (except array). I was a bit confused by the official documentation on this point

Comment: [explitive] [explitive] [explitive], been fighting with this for 2 days. thanks @Chris Fulstow, such an obscure but key feature!

Comment: Emphasis on _The _id field doesn't have to be an MongoDB ObjectId_. If you are using ObjectId or Bson attributes then your object is no longer POCO (plain old CLR object), so really, that's the answer. Avoid using them if you can.

Comment: @ChadHedgcock i follow you here. But If i dont have any property on my poco class that corresponds to this I get an error while loading the document. like " _id couldt map to anything"

Comment: @Jepzen bit late to game but the class attribute [BsonIgnoreExtraElements] might fix that issue.

Answer (score 11):

You have to add a property (or field) for id and tell serializer which id generator you'd like to use.

```
[BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(ObjectIdGenerator))]
public object ThingyId { get; set; }
```

There are 3 available in MongoDb Driver or you can write your own. More info at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-WriteacustomIdgenerator

Comment: That link seems to be broken now.

Answer (score 6):

I generally wrap Thingy:

```
public class MongoThingy
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public Thingy Thingy { get; set; }
}
```

It makes it a lot easier, as often times class Thingy comes from a different library over which I have no control. It's also easier to deserialize in order to hand it over to someone else for processsing.

Answer (score 2):

Add a property as follows:

```
public BsonObjectId Id { get; set; }
```

The MongoDB driver automatically converts `Id` to `_id` during serialization\deserializtion.

Comment: thx - I have a feeling that there is a set of docs, samples or something that I am missing :-)

Comment: @Bryan Migliorisi - this doesnt work. THe insert (or Save) fails telling me that Id cannot be null

Comment: @Bryan Migliorisi - official c# driver from mongodb git site, downloaded yesterday

Comment: The data type of the Id property should be ObjectId, not BsonObjectId. Although BsonObjectId seems reasonable also, so I'll create JIRA request to support it as well.

Comment: Interesting... Robert, I've used BsonObjectId for every entity in my code without any problems using your driver.

Comment: i had it as BsonObjectID - which explains it

Comment: As long as you assigned a value to the BsonObjectId everything was fine. It was only when you left it null and called Save expecting to autogenerate a unique value for it that there was a problem.

Comment: This JIRA has now been implemented: jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-231. I still recommend that you use ObjectId as the data type of your Id property, but if for some reason you prefer BsonObjectId it is now fully supported.

Comment: Does ObjectId automatically create a BsonObjectId value?  I've been instantiating the object in my constructors.

Comment: There's some information about the difference between ObjectId and BsonObjectId at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-ObjectIdandBsonObjectId. In general, if you are working with BsonDocuments you will be using BsonObjectIds, and if you are working with C# POCOs you will be using ObjectId (although since there is an automatic conversion from ObjectId to BsonObjectId you can also use ObjectIds with BsonDocuments).

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Thingy
{
      public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
      public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

According to class

Where needed, use the following code:

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<Thingy>("db_Thingy");
Thingy tg= new Thingy();
tg.Foo = "Hello";
collection.insert(tg);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way by https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

namespace BooksApi.Models
{
    public class Book
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("Name")]
        public string BookName { get; set; }

        (...)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Chris Christopher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5041099/chris-christopher) in a comment above, you can use `BsonIgnoreExtraElements` class attribute:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Thingy
{
     public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

This way you don't have to add an Id property with some other `BSon` attribute.